# How to remove everything after the first word?

Tags: string, file, batch-file, text

I would like to remove everything after the first word in each line of this text document. It works for simple character removal, but does not work when I try to remove the "|" of the text file.

[image]

**I am trying to use the following code:**

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set /p txtfile=Text File Name: 
    Echo.
set /p "search=Search for: "
    Echo.
set /p "replace=Replace to: "

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%txtfile%.txt" ^& break ^> "%txtfile%.txt" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%txtfile%.tmp" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )

    ren "%txtfile%".tmp "%txtfile%".txt 

pause
```

**But the following error is appearing:**

[image]

Comment: Please insert the sample data as text rather than as image, so answerers can simply copy them for testing their code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the pipe character `|` which is trying to be executed due to immediate expansion of the variable `%search%`.

A possible work-around is to use an interim variable assignment (`set "line=..."`) which allows quotation marks, so the pipe is no longer recognised, and then to use only delayed expansion in your `echo` command line -- like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /P txtfile="Text File Name: "
echo/
set /P search="Search for: "
echo/
set /P replace="Replace to: "

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('type "%txtfile%.txt" ^& break ^> "%txtfile%.txt"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%txtfile%.txt" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)

pause
endlocal
```

Another solution is to use delayed expansion also for `!search!` and `!replace!`; for this to work, you cannot directly nest delayed expansion, so you need to use a `for /F` loop to do the nesting -- like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /P txtfile="Text File Name: "
echo/
set /P search="Search for: "
echo/
set /P replace="Replace to: "

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('type "%txtfile%.txt" ^& break ^> "%txtfile%.txt"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "delims=" %%j in ("!search!=!replace!") do (
        >>"%txtfile%.txt" echo(!line:%%j!
    )
    endlocal
)

pause
endlocal
```

---

Instead of redirecting (`>>`) every single output line individually, you could also redirect the whole `for /F` loop by `>`, but then you need to use a different file than the one you read -- see this (showing only the first variant from above):

```cmd
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /P txtfile="Text File Name: "
echo/
set /P search="Search for: "
echo/
set /P replace="Replace to: "

> "%txtfile%.tmp" (
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%txtfile%.txt") do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)

move /Y "%txtfile%.tmp" "%txtfile%.txt" > nul

pause
endlocal
```

This approach is much better in terma of performance, particularly for huge input files.

Comment: Hello! it worked almost perfectly, but it's having difficulty saving the final result, see: https://imgur.com/9PWtq0a

Comment: I guess this error is caused by `ren` as file `%txtfile%.txt` already exists; actually you do not need to rename a file, simply replace `>>"%txtfile%.tmp"` in the loop by `>>"%txtfile%.txt"`...

Comment: Thanks, i solved! The problem was in a part that he passed the information of the .txt to the same ".txt", so at the time of saving, the file already existed. So I just had to write the information in a ".tmp" file, to go over to a ".txt" file afterwards.

Comment: Check out my edited answer, I included an alternative and improved method of file handling...

Answer (score 0):

After understanding a few previous codes, I finally solve the problem with this code:

```
@Echo off

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set /P txtfile="Text File Name: "
echo/
set /P search="Search for: "
echo/
set /P replace="Replace to: "

for /F "delims=" %%i in ('type "%txtfile%.txt" ^& break ^> %txtfile%.tmp') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >> %txtfile%.tmp echo(!line!
    endlocal
)

ren %txtfile%.tmp CleanText.txt

pause
endlocal
```